# Why poi-4.1.2 for xls dos not find dependencies even though classpath is right?

Tags: java, excel, netbeans, ant, apache-poi

I am building a simple project using Ant (not Maven as I need the project to be build and distributed in an .msi package when it is finished), added all the dependencies according to [this](https://www.codejava.net/coding/how-to-read-excel-files-in-java-using-apache-poi) article (end even more poi jar files) to the classpath and still I am getting the following error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/math3/util/ArithmeticUtils

It seems that there are more dependencies that the poi-4.1.2.jar file does not contain.  Can I add them by hand or will it require more dependencies after that?  And where do I have to look. (org.apache.commons.*)

As said building this project with Maven is not an option.

Here are all the imports I have in my class that fails to compile:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
```

And those are the jar files added to the Libraries in NetBeans

```
poi-4.1.2.jar
poi-excelant-4.1.2.jar
poi-ooxml-4.1.2.jar
poi-ooxml-schemas-4.1.2.jar
xmlbeans-3.1.0.jar
```

Comment: https://poi.apache.org/components/index.html#components

Comment: If you download the binary package of Apache POI it comes with all the required dependencies in the lib folder, just add those!

Answer (score 0):

You can look on the [website](https://poi.apache.org/components/index.html#components) what dependency you need for general operations.
Still, for me it seems, that all the import-dependecy are correct. Maybe the dependencies are not correctly added?

Every dependency can be added per hand, even those you mentioned in your post. There are two options:

1. add the dependency via POM (this one I cannot tell in more detail)
2. in Projects Structure:
   go to Modules, then Dependency. Here you can add any dependency vial MAVEN PROJECT library. In your case just write org.apache.poi in the search field, click the search button and look  up the list of dependency you need. Here is a picture of the last step without the list, the screenshot did not allow it.[image]

Also, it can even happen, that your setting in the project structure is not correct. When I did everything, the dependecies were added with the Scope of "Compile", like in the picture [image]

I did the whole procedure in IntelliJ, but it should be quite the same in all other IDE's.